# mediaElement works on Chrome but not Firefox or Edge (web audio api / angularJS)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, web-audio-api

I can't find my error here. I'm connecting a soundcloud track to a `audioNode` and it to a `biquadFilter` so I can apply equalization to it. All of this inside an AngularJs App

It works without any trouble in chrome, but in Firefox and MS Edge I'm getting this error:

```
Error: this.source.mediaElement is undefined
  soundcloudObject.prototype.playPause@http://localhost:8080/app/app.module.js:535:13
```

Here is the relevant part of the code

```
app.factory("soundcloudObject", function(){
function soundcloudObject(url){
    if (typeof url === 'undefined') {  
        url= "http://api.soundcloud.com/tracks/119451720/stream";
        }

    var clientId = "?client_id=MY_CLIENT_ID";
    var song = new Audio();
    song.crossOrigin = "anonymous";
    song.src = url + clientId;

    this.source  = scope.audioContext.createMediaElementSource(song);        
}

var isPlaying = false;
soundcloudObject.prototype.playPause = function(){        
    if (isPlaying === true){
        this.source.disconnect(); 
            isPlaying = false;
            console.log("Music Is Not Playing");
    }
    else{
        this.source.connect(scope.musicEq); 
 this.source.mediaElement.play(); //##################//**LINE 535**//
        isPlaying = true;
    }
}; 

soundcloudObject.prototype.play = function(){
    this.source.disconnect();
    this.source.connect(scope.musicEq ); // connect to EQ Node
    this.source.mediaElement.play();
    isPlaying = true;
};



soundcloudObject.prototype.disconnect = function(){

    this.source.disconnect();
}; 

return soundcloudObject;

});
```

I create a soundcloudObject with all the data in my controller, and then call it  in my view to `.play()` or `.playPause()`.
The object (called soundcloud) exists, as I can see in my log:

```
scope.soundcloud
Object { source: MediaElementAudioSourceNode }
```

[image: soundcloud object]

But then I call `soundcloud.play()` and I get  `TypeError: this.source.mediaElement is undefined`

I'm clueless...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like `.mediaElement`is deprecated.

the fix was go back in the node chain  and use song (the media element source itself) `song.play()` and it worked in firefox, chrome and edge.